# Tools for native memory leak analysis

Tags: java, memory-leaks, native-code

I am suspecting a native memory leak in my java code. Are there any tools which do native memory profiling? Also, does any tool support native memory analysis of a running java process?

Thanks!!

Edit:
I have already tried Memory Validator and Purify but it seems they support only 32-bit processes. Is there some tool similar to the above ones which can simply attach to a running windows process and give us native memory analysis for that particular process?

Answer (score 4):

The [Troubleshooting guide for Java SE 6 with Hotspot VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html#gbyvk) contains a fairly elaborate section on techniques to aid in detecting native memory leaks. These include:

- wrapping all memory allocation and deallocation calls to track the amount of memory used.
- relying on platform specific support like the debug support provided by the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler or on mtrace (and MALLOC_TRACE) to debug memory allocations on Linux.
- using memory leak analysis tools like Rational Purify.

among others. Notably, the article mentions that no ideal solution exists for all platforms.

Also, consider using the `-Xcheck:jni` flag that appears to be available in most JVMs. The `-X` flag itself indicates that the flag is non-standard, but the flag appears to be available in the [IBM JDK](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v5r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.50/html/win_memory.html), [Oracle JRockit R28](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionx.htm#BABJGFFC), and even the Oracle/Sun JVM. Enabling the flag switches on a mode where wrappers are added around JNI calls, thereby allowing you to track illegal arguments passed to JVM calls as noted in the [JNI programmers' guide and specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/pitfalls.html). While, it's use in detecting memory leaks is subjective, it would definitely help if you suspect that the leak is being caused due to invalid parameters being issued.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK **you can't do it with Java tools like JProfiler, JVisualVM etc.** If you have memory leak in native code use tools for native code. You ie. can run it from C (i.e. loading jvm.dll). You can look at this articles [finding memory leaks using Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or [Memory Leak Detection in C++ (Linux)](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6556)

Note: of course if you leak is connected to heap leak (forgot about deleteglobalref) you can find it with Java tools, but it is very rare in JNI.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on an open-source project named "MySafe" (https://github.com/serkan-ozal/mysafe) It basicly intercepts and monitors "Unsafe" calls. (In fact, it makes more than). With version 2.0, it can be useful for tracking and detecting "Unsafe" based native memory leaks.

Demo code: https://github.com/serkan-ozal/mysafe/blob/master/src/test/java/tr/com/serkanozal/mysafe/NativeMemoryLeakHuntingDemo.java

Diagram showing source of the leak: https://github.com/serkan-ozal/mysafe/blob/master/src/test/resources/native-memory-leak-hunting.png

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose native memory leak, JIT code symbol mapping and Linux recent profiling tools are required: `perf`, `perf-map-agent` and `bcc`.

Please refer to details in related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52767721/737790

Many thanks to [Brendan Gregg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Gregg)

Answer (score 0):

These are tools you can use for debugging

1. libtcmalloc HPROF: For heap profiling
2. The jcmd Utility, PSS for the process: Can help in confirming a native leak.
3. Native Memory Tracking: Tracking native memory leak in JVM (only works for allocation inside JVM)
4. Core dump analysis, pmap and gdb checking for anon blocks and process memory overtime
5. -Xcheck:jni

Further details can be found out here
https://www.bro-code.in/blog/java-debugging-native-memory-leak
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html#gbyvk

Answer (score -6):

I'm a big fan of JProfiler.  That's the best tool for profiling and memory leaks.  It's fairly cheap relative to most tools, really easy to learn, and lots of features.

http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html

Comment: JProfiler is a good profiler which also allows tracking of object creation. But thats not related to native heap allocations.